# Covered cat litter box with space?

Tags: cats, toilet-training

I have a [regular covered litter box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI5PA.png) that my cats use. But I've noticed that they always poop where the entrance is, and that makes sense. Who wants to walk on poopy sand?

Are there any covered litter boxes that have space around the litter? So they can walk around the litter box and poop/pee wherever they want. And it's still covered.

In other words, instead of entering the litter box and being on top of the sand, it would be like a small bathroom: they go into the litter box, and then they can walk around to see where they can poop/pee.

Thanks.

Comment: this litterbox is large https://www.catit.com/products/litter-box-acc/ maby get one similar to this one.

Comment: That is a brilliant idea... a litter box with a stable raised walkway around it, with everything enclosed by a clear dome. It would make cats who like the balance on the edge of liter boxes and poop inside very happy.